# unknown mount option `relatime'

Tags: bash, mount

When I run `bash ./rebuild.sh` I get the following error:

```
vagrant@user:/var/www/html/wp-content/xdebug$ bash ./rebuild.sh
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
shtool at '/var/www/html/wp-content/xdebug/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable.
Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this script.
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332287/3539592) I should "Remove noexec flag from /var/www/html/". When I try this, I get another error:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,noexec /var/www/html/
unknown mount option `relatime'
valid options:
  rw         mount read write (default)
  ro         mount read only
  uid       =<arg> default file owner user id
  gid       =<arg> default file owner group id
  ttl       =<arg> time to live for dentry
  iocharset =<arg> i/o charset (default utf8)
  convertcp =<arg> convert share name from given charset to utf8
  dmode     =<arg> mode of all directories
  fmode     =<arg> mode of all regular files
  umask     =<arg> umask of directories and regular files
  dmask     =<arg> umask of directories
  fmask     =<arg> umask of regular files
```

I'm pretty stuck here as I have not found much out there on this issue. How do I 'fix' this?

UPDATE:

From the xdebug README file `./rebuild.sh` : "This will run `phpize`, `./configure`, `make clean`, `make` and `make install`."

When I run `phpize` alone I also get the same error. What is causing this?

Comment: What is `rebuild.sh`?

Comment: From the xdebug README file: "This will run ``phpize``, ``./configure``, ``make clean``, ``make`` and ``make
install``." When I run `phpize` alone I also get the same error.

Comment: @Hugo in the mount script?

Comment: @hunterint Nevermind, I was wrong

Comment: @Hugo see `man mount`, `relatime` is a valid option.

Comment: What is your filesystem? It probably does not support the `relatime` option. However I fail to see how you can get the error you quote with the command you run. How did you set up `/var/www/html`? How is it defined in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You'll have to excuse my Linux ignorance, I'm not sure what type of file system I have. When I run `blkid` I get:
`/dev/sda1: ... 
/dev/sda5: ...
/dev/mapper/vagrant--vg-root: UUID="..." TYPE="ext4"`. Not sure if that helps.

This is all apart of a vagrant ubuntu virtual box that I access using `vagrant ssh` from windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you runnig vagrant provider virtualbox and you wnat remove relatime just put parameter norelatime like this:

```
mount -o remount,ttl=0,norelatime /var/www/html/
```